# Error: Unable to export features with empty geometry to asset

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am extracting land use data for a bunch of points (var table) in Google Earth Engine. But when I run the code, it gives the error:

> Unable to export features with null geometry. (Error code: 3).

I tried with a different point dataset and it results in the same error.

How can I solve this issue?

Below is my code.

```js
var table = ee.FeatureCollection('users/xxx/points');
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD12Q1');

dataset = dataset.select('LC_Type1');
dataset = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2022-01-01'));
dataset=dataset.map(function(img){
  var outi=ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('system:time_end')));
  outi=outi.addBands(img);
  return(outi)
});
//table=table.filterBounds(ali);
var extraction = dataset.map(function(img){ 
  var df= img.sampleRegions({
  'collection': table,
  'scale': 1000,
});
return(df)
});
extraction=extraction.flatten();

Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: extraction,
  description:'exportToTableAssetExample',
  assetId:'xxx/xxx' 
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `'geometries'` argument in `sampleRegions` to `true` (to override the default, `false`). In this way, the sampled data should include its geometries.

```
var extraction = dataset.map(function(img){ 
    var df= img.sampleRegions({
      'collection': table,
      'scale': 1000,
      'geometries': true 
    });
  return(df);
});
```